# docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount

Tags: docker

I am trying to create an **Anonymous Volume** with docker but it throws this error:

[image]

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount {Destination:C:/Program Files/Git/app/node_modules Type:bind Source:/var/lib/docker/volumes/51c96f13f0232b1d052a91fdb0d8ed60881420ee214aa46ae85e16dfa4bbece0/_data Options:[rbind]}: mount destination C:/Program Files/Git/app/node_modules not absolute: unknown.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue today while running hyperledger fabric on windows OS, it seems to be a mounting issue. The error went away when I ran the below command on git bash.

```
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must open up the command prompt (powershell/cmd) at your working directory, if feedback is your working directory open up the cmd at feedback and then, in windows, in the powershell/cmd use:
**docker run -p (localhost port):(container port) -v %cd%:/app** 
instead of **$(pwd)** use **%cd%** it worked for me. I probably think the issue is with gitbash, you could use powershell instead, I came across the exact same problem just now and gitbash gave the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got a permanent fix for windows, docker volumes has an issue in windows https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693/7. So we could use:
**docker run -p 8080:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v //d/Desktop/Docker/react-app/front-end:/app** 
if your files where in c drive use **//c/Desktop/Docker/react-app/front-end:/app** instead of **//d/Desktop/Docker/react-app/front-end:/app** 
And yeah remember to use powershell not gitbash it also has an issue.
If your using a react application make sure that you have **.env** file with **CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true**

Answer (score 0):

Also, be sure you are running the docker command in the same folder where the `docker-compose.yml` lives. Otherwise, the docker command can execute fine until it reaches the point where it loads the volume and then trying to access the relative path might cause it to throw the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem with Windows and it was solved by changing the value after `-v`.

Like this:

```
docker run --name websiteTwo -v "/C/Users/myDirectoy/docker":/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```